# Cannot connect to MySQL docker instance via DataGrip application

Tags: mysql, docker, connection, datagrip

I have managed to successfully connect to a docker instance running MySQL via the mysql command line utility. However, I am struggling to do so via DataGrip application from JetBrains.

My mysql cli command is as follows:

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 --port=8181 -uroot
```

The connection string that is generated in DataGrip is:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8181
```

The error I am getting from DataGrip interface is:

```
[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Is there anything that need to change in DataGrip that I am missing. I have read that the connection has to also be done via TCP. Not sure how to check that DataGrip is doing that.

**Update:** I eventually found the problem was the docker container I was using. It seems DataGrip is not able to connect to version 8.0.1 (mysql:8.0.1) mysql docker container. I tested using version 5.7 of the container and could successfully connect.

Comment: Please, send a screenshot of connection window to maxim.sobolevskiy[at]jetbrains.com and I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks Jetbrains team. You tried to help me sending several emails.

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for reporting, Leon!

Answer (score 10):

I was having an issue connecting MySQL 8.0.3 using DataGrip. You need to download the JDBC driver from Oracle [website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html). Select Developer Releases (Since this is an unstable version). The 8.0.8 version worked for me. Download and save in a project folder or something similar on your computer. You will gonna need it later.

- Go to DataGrip: File > DataSources. Click on the `+` and select `Driver`:
- [Screenshot of the Step above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M1q5.png)
- On the section `Driver Files` > `Additional files` click on the `+` and select the `jar` file you just downloaded
- After that on the `Class` dropdown select `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- Mark `Dialect` as `MySQL`
- On the section URL templates, put the **Name** as `default` and **Template** as `jdbc:mysql://{host::localhost}?[:{port::3306}][/{database}?][\?<&,user={user},password={password},{:identifier}={:identifier}>]`
- Click on apply

Done!

[Screenshot of MySQL 8.0.3 running on Datagrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjHoa.png)

Add a new datasource using the new driver.

If you find the following error:

```
[01S00] The server time zone value 'PDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support
```

You can do a temporary fix going to the `Advanced` tab and setting the `serverTimezone` variable for `UTC` as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post!

Comment: Using MySQL Connector/J  8.0.15 in DataGrip, I had to use serverTimezone = America/Los_Angeles  instead of PDT to make it work.

Comment: `use mysql;
update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where User='root';
flush privileges;` also solves the problem though

Answer (score 0):

There are no *.jar-files anymore. Only *.deb-packages for my OS on the Oracle site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

So I selected driver Amazon Aurora MySQL for my MySQL 8.0.3 in docker.
It works!